# Google Maps api2 with Android Studio issue

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

Using Eclipse I converted several Google Maps v1 to v2 without many problems.  One of my services uses the V1 GeoPoint class a great deal and I was able to use the code unaltered by importing `import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint`.  I have a half dozen apps running maps V2 with using this GeoPoint class.

Now I'm over on Android Studio converting my last maps V1 app to maps V2 but even though I have the same import statement I'm getting an exception at at run time when I reference the GeoPoint class.  Saying...

> NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.

So the same code runs fine when testing in Eclipse but blows when testing in Android Studio.

EDIT: The GeoPoint class compiles fine in AS it just blows at run time.  I don't know what would cause this.

If it helps I include my manifest file and the module `Build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.deanblakely.mttTrial"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.deanblakely.mttTrial"

    android:versionCode="22"
    android:versionName="2.22" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

        <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.deanblakely.mttTrial.PSActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name="com.deanblakely.mttTrial.LicenseCheck"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        </activity>    


        <service
            android:name="com.deanblakely.mttTrial.StalkService"
            android:exported="false" />
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="not the actual key" />

            <!--' Release key is not the actual release key'-->     
            <!--' Debug key is not the actual debug key'-->     


    </application>
    <!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Improve your **`build.gradle`**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

And add this your `Manifest`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.deanblakely.mttTrial.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: I put in com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' as AS is telling me that is the latest so I put that in.  Everyone says MAPS_RECEIVE is no longer needed.  Anyway, your suggestions did not work.